# How many job vacancies do we have if no discipline can be without at least one teacher?

Tags: combinatorics

11 teacher vacancies for 5 subjects, it is necessary to decide how many teachers will work in each discipline. How many job vacancies do we have if no discipline can be without at least one teacher?

C(m+n-1, n-1) is correct?

Comment: Just to be clear: there are 5 subjects and 11 job vacancies, and there must be at least one vacancy per subject?

Comment: @jvdhooft  Yes, there are 5 subjects and 11 job vacancies, and there must be at least one vacancy per subject.

Comment: In that case, I believe the answer below is what you are looking for.

Comment: As options of answers are: a) 495,b) 3960, c) 450, d) 1485 and e) 491.

Comment: Can you quote the question directly?

Comment: @jvdhooft We have 11 instructor positions open in the school and 5 classes that need instructors. We need to decide how many instructors each class will get. In how many ways can we distribute those instructors if we know that each class needs to have at least one?

Answer (score 1):

There are five subjects and eleven job vacancies. Every subject must have at least one vacancy, which leaves six vacancies to be distributed among the five subjects. This is a [stars and bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), for which the number of possible combinations equals:

$${11-5+5-1 \choose 5-1} = {10 \choose 4} = 210$$

**Edit:** To verify this result, you can use the following (not so elegant) Python script:

```
i = 0
for a in range(1, 12):
  for b in range(1, 12 - a):
    for c in range(1, 12 - a - b):
      for d in range(1, 12 - a - b - c):
        for e in range(1, 12 - a - b - c - d):
          if a + b + c + d + e == 11:
            i += 1
print i
```

Comment: As options of answers are: a) 495,b) 3960, c) 450, d) 1485 and e) 491.

Comment: We have 11 instructor positions open in the school and 5 classes that need instructors. We need to decide how many instructors each class will get. In how many ways can we distribute those instructors if we know that each class needs to have at least one?

Comment: @NathanPalmares As I stated before, the answer is 210. I updated my answer with some sample Python code, which will show you the same result.